# Get FQDN (fully qualified domain name) from client machine

Tags: c#, .net-5, httpcontext, fqdn

I'm working on a project that will include Windows tablets as a Terminals and they will be under VPN. Setting up the tablets will not be our job, we only need to provide some endpoints for them and we'll need to authenticate the API calls from them with their FQDN. The project is .net5 Web API.

Previously the requirement was that we will use the IP address of the terminals for authenticating them and I can easily use this code for getting that:

```
var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
```

However the request was changed and we will need to use FQDN for authentication.
The problem is that I can not get FQDN from HTTP Context as I can take the IP address.

Is there any way to get this parameter from the device?

Comment: By FQDN do you mean the Active Directory they are joined to? They will not have their own actual FQDN. They will appear to be coming from the gateway of the VPN so I guess you could do a DNS lookup on that IP.

Comment: FQDN and IP address are orthogonal: there might bem multiple machines using the same IP address (NAT) or there may be multiple IP addresses for the same machine. I suggest you ask for the FQDN in the first place